# Oracle aggregate functions on strings

Tags: oracle

I have an employee with multiple managers. The  manager name field has (firstname,lastname) and the email field has(last.first@email.com).There is no Mgr id. 
So, when I try to group this by employee id to get the max of Mgr name and email, some times I end up getting the wrong name/email id combination.

ex:

```
person  Mgr_name    Mgr_email
------- ---------   ----------
111     brad,pitt   pitt.brad@test.com
111     mike,clark  clark.mike@test.com
```

when I group it by person and get the max(mgr_name),mgr_email, I get

```
person  max(Mgr_name)    max(Mgr_email)
------- ---------        ----------
111     mike,clark        pitt.brad@test.com
```

How do I get the correct email/name combination?

Comment: How do you know which of the two values to pick?  Is it equally correct to get "brad,pitt" and "pitt.brad@test.com" as it is to get "mike,clark" and "clark.mike@test.com" so long as you don't get one value from each row?

Comment: Perhaps, the latest of the two will be ideal. Sorry for being vague.

Comment: Define "latest".  Is there some `date` or `timestamp` column that can be used to identify the latest row?  Is there a monotonically increasing key column that can be used?

Comment: There is a time stamp. So, doing a dense rank over them and ordering it by the time stamp gave me what I was looking for. Thanks for driving me home :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use row_number analytical function instead:

```
with t(person  ,Mgr_name ,   Mgr_email) as (
select 111     ,'brad,pitt'  , 'pitt.brad@test.com' from dual union all
select 111     ,'mike,clark' , 'clark.mike@test.com' from dual )

select person  ,Mgr_name ,   Mgr_email from (
select t1.*, row_number() over (order by mgr_name) num from t t1)
where num = 1
```

This get max mgr_name with correct email.

Output:

```
    PERSON MGR_NAME   MGR_EMAIL          
---------- ---------- -------------------
       111 brad,pitt  pitt.brad@test.com
```

Comment: dense rank gave me what I was looking for. So, here is another question. If I have 20 fields that I want to fix. Will adding dense rank to all 20, create a performance issue? I am looking at >million rows.

Comment: Analytic functions add performance to queries, but i don't really understand your point, could you put this as other question, with more details and sample data?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a subselect to obtain the max mgr_name for each person in the table then join it back to the base results to limit to only display each persons "Max" manager...

```
SELECT t1.Person, t1.Mgr_name, t1.mgr_email
FROM tableName t1
INNER JOIN (Select max(mgr_name) mname, Person from TableName group by person) t2
 on t1.mgr_name = t2.mname
 and t2.Person = T1.Person
```